# Historical 'identify this' questions - should we allow them?

Tags: discussion, scope

We have several 'identify-this' type questions, which are great - someone you want to visit the field shown in the Windows desktop, or a beach you saw on a screensaver.

However, I'm uncertain about historical ones, like:

[Where this picture was taken ~100 years ago?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25069/101)

My reasoning against it:

- there's a good chance it won't exist like that any more. Fields, beaches and castles, sure, but a dirt track into a village?
- I'm not even sure it's identifiable
- why is it being asked? they're just trying to find a photo their grandfather took, or are they wanting to visit it? This is a travel website, after all.

I can, however, also see reasons for it - you may want to visit the village your grandfather took a photo of back in the 50s, or something.

So...thoughts?

Answer (score 11):

I think in this particular case it should be allowed, as the OP seems to be pretty certain that it still exists.

Furthermore it seems to more than "a dirt track into a village", as the village seems to be build on a cliff of some sort and seems to have some building that look pretty old and historical, so I guess there's a real chance that this still exists and it does look like nice place to visit.

I am not sure if the "why is it being asked" part is so important. If you look at the questions under the "where-on-earth" tag, there are a couple questions asking for places based on background pictures or random photographs where I doubt there is more real interest to visit the place.

Comment: I think the "why is it being asked" should be largely irrelevant.  If we make it important, people will just lie and say they want to travel there.  Either the questions are on-topic or not, the intent to travel shouldn't magically make off-topic questions on-topic.